# Picker conflicts with NavigationLink gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to create the following card view.

[image: Screenshot of card]

With the following code to achieve it.

```
struct SimpleGame: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

enum PlayingStatus: String {
    case In = "I"
    case Out = "O"
    case Undecided = "U"
}


struct TestView: View {
    let games: [SimpleGame] = [
        .init(name: "First"),
        .init(name: "Second")
    ]
    
    @State private var currentStatus: PlayingStatus = .Undecided
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(games) { game in
                Section {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(value: game) {
                            Text("\(game.name)")
                        }
                        Divider()
                        Picker("Going?", selection: $currentStatus) {
                            Text("No Response")
                                .tag(PlayingStatus.Undecided)
                            Text("Going")
                                .tag(PlayingStatus.In)
                            Text("Not going")
                                .tag(PlayingStatus.Out)
                        }
                            .font(.body)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Game.self) { game in
                Text("Detail View")
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Upcoming")
        }
    }
}
```

But a tap on element wrapped by NavigationLink is registering as a tap on the Picker. Anyone know of a way around this?

iOS 16/Xcode 14

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `GameVersus` does? Also, is everything embedded inside a VStack?

Comment: With very limited code provided, it is tough to reproduce locally. It would be helpful if you created a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I did spin something up on my end similar to what you posted, but was not seeing any issues. Some things that come to mind: Is the entire view embedded in a navigation view? Is all content enclosed in a VStack? You could potentially put the navigation link & the remaining code in separate Groups - i.e. Group {}

Comment: Apologies. Just updated with the full code sample. Hope this is more clear. Thanks both for taking a look.

Comment: What was asked, is to show a minimal reproducible code example,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
      some code we can compile and execute and test any answers.

Comment: Well, the questions seems to indicate the embedding and embedded parts of the code are important and necessary to understand the issue.

Comment: But i see what you mean, let me work on that.

Comment: Just updated the code sample. It should be easily copy pasteable into a new view and reproduce (hopefully*) the issue I am seeing. Thanks in advance. I shall iterate on making it more minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
List {
    ForEach(games, id: \.name) { game in
        Section {
            NavigationLink(value: game) {
                Text("\(game.name)")
            }
            // -- here
            VStack {
                Divider()
                Picker("Going?", selection: $currentStatus) {
                    Text("No Response").tag(PlayingStatus.Undecided)
                    Text("Going").tag(PlayingStatus.In)
                    Text("Not going").tag(PlayingStatus.Out)
                }
                .font(.body)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this work this way? Is this because picker likes to takeover whichever structural element its embedded in?

Answer (score -1):

What often works for me is extending the view.

```
    struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {

       List {
         ForEach(games, id: \.name) { game in
         Section {
            NavigationLink(value: game) {
                Text("\(game.name)")
            }
            // -- here
            VStack {
                Divider()
                picker
            }
        }
    }
   }
  }
}

Extension TestView {
   private var picker: some View {
     Picker("Going?", selection: $currentStatus) {
                    Text("No Response").tag(PlayingStatus.Undecided)
                    Text("Going").tag(PlayingStatus.In)
                    Text("Not going").tag(PlayingStatus.Out)
                }
                .font(.body)
  }
}
```